# Pascal exitcode 201

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I am having problems with this program. The project is for it to be a cash register.

```
Program Cash_Register;
var
    ItemsPrices: array[1..20] of real;
    ItemsNames: array[1..20] of string;
    Item_Number: integer;
    NameNumber: integer;
    PriceTracker: integer; {1}
    NameTracker: integer;  {1}
    To_End_Or_Not_To_End: string;
    PriceNumber: integer;        {0}
    Subtotal: real;
    gst_sum: real;
    Final_Total: real;

const
    GST: real = 0.125;          {0.125}
    Base: integer = 21;         {21}
    CR: string = #13;          {#13}
    LF: string = #10;          {#10}
    CRLF: string = #13#10;    {CR + LF}

begin
    {Variable and constant assignment}
    PriceTracker:= 1;
    NameTracker:= 1;
    PriceNumber:= 0;

    {This area below starts the name taking and price taking}
    while (PriceTracker AND NameTracker) < Base do
    begin
            {This area below Asks the user for the name of the product}
            Writeln('Please enter the name of product ');
            write(Item_Number);
            write(' please.');
            readln(ItemsNames[Item_Number]);

            {This area below asks the user for the price of said item}
            Writeln('Please enter the price of product ');
            write(Item_Number);
            write(' please.');
            readln(ItemsPrices[Item_Number]);

            {This area below imcrements the counter by 1}
            Item_Number:= Item_Number + 1;

            {This area below asks the user if they want ot continue or not}
            writeln('Do you want to stop entering items? [Yes/No]');
            readln(To_End_Or_Not_To_End);

            {This area below will determine the programs path}
            if To_End_Or_Not_To_End = 'Yes' then
                    continue

            else
                    break


    end;

    NameNumber:= Item_Number + 1;
    PriceNumber:= Item_Number + 1;
    Item_Number:= 1;

    {This area below defines the code that will create the Subtotal}
    while Item_Number < PriceNumber  do
    begin
            Subtotal:= Subtotal + ItemsPrices[Item_Number];
            Item_Number:= Item_Number + 1;

    end;

    gst_sum:= Subtotal * GST;
    Final_Total:= Subtotal + gst;

    Item_Number:= 1;

    {This area below prints the List of items and prices in reciept form}
    while Item_Number < NameNumber do
    begin
            write(ItemsNames[Item_Number]);
            write('        Bz$ ');
            write(ItemsPrices[Item_Number]);
            write(CRLF);
            Item_Number:= Item_Number + 1;
            continue

    end;

    {This area below prints a reciept for the customer}
    write('Subtotal'#9#9);
    write(Subtotal);

    writeln('GST tax 12.5%'#9#9 + 'Bz$');
    write(gst_sum);

    writeln('Total'#9#9 + 'Bz$');
    write(Final_Total);
    write(CRLF);

    writeln('Tips:______________________________');
    writeln(CRLF);

    writeln('Total:_____________________________');
    writeln(CRLF);

    writeln('Print Name:________________________');
    writeln(CRLF);

    writeln('Signature__________________________');
end.
```

But it compiled and it throws an error at me saying "excited with exitcode 201." I don't want to change the structure and I have no idea what is going on with the compiler as it refuses to run without immediately exiting. What i'm Trying is to see what happens as it is exiting, because I managed to catch a glimpse of the text that should appear on startup. If someone knows what is wrong, do please inform me.

Comment: Please do some research before posting questions here. [A Google search for ***freepascal error 201***](https://www.google.com/search?q=freepascal+error+201) provided some immediate clues, without even visiting any of the links returned.

Comment: Well, with current prices, noobs don't use Delphi anymore......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your problem is staring you in the face, but I suspect you don't know enough yet to realise what it is.

When these lines execute

```
Writeln('Please enter the name of product ');
            write(Item_Number);
            write(' please.');
```

what you see is

> Please enter the name of product
>   0 please.

This is telling you that the value of `Item_Number` is 0 (zero).  Your next statement is

```
readln(ItemsNames[Item_Number]);
```

You've declared your `ItemNames` array as having elements 1 to 20, so there is no `ItemNames[0]`, which is what your `readln` is trying to read.  Same thing with your

```
readln(ItemsPrices[Item_Number]);
```

To fix this, assign the value 1 to `Item_Number` before your `while` loop begins.

Next, add the statement

```
readln();
```

as the very last line of your program (before the `end.`).  That will stop the console window closing before you have a chance to read what your program outputs.

The above should at least get you started on debugging you program.  You'll need to learn how to debug the rest yourself.  Google yourself some debugger tutorials, e.g. this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZ90IBa9_8M

Until you get to grips with debugging your own code, you will get absolutely nowhere in Pascal or any other programming language.  Others may disagree, but imo it is probably the single most important skill a programmer needs.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll try that, It should work and everything.

Comment: It Works! Thanks again!

Comment: @AlvaroHabetHulse:  Any reason you "unaccepted" my answer?

Comment: My bad, I must have double clicked